# R POSIXlt timestamp conversion do not know how to convert 'df1$timestamp' to class “POSIXlt”

Tags: r, datetime, sparkr

Hello all I am facing issue while converting timestamp to POSIXlt, later from this timestamp o need to extract Year,month,dayofmoth,hour,min,sec

```
    2015-12-01 00:04:39 is my timestamp
```

and here is my try

```
getwd()
rm(list=ls())
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(reshape)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)
library(SparkR)

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/spark").libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))

sc <- sparkR.init(master="local","RwordCount")
args <- commandArgs(trailing = TRUE)

sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

df1 <- read.df(sqlContext, "hdfs://master:9000/test.csv",  header='true', source = "com.databricks.spark.csv", inferSchema='true', stringsAsFactors = F)


 if("timestamp" %in% colnames(df1)){
     df1$pTime <- as.POSIXlt(df1$timestamp, format= "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S") 
  }else {
     df1$pTime <- as.POSIXlt(df1$Timestamp, format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
}
```

but getting error here **do not know how to convert 'df1$timestamp' to class “POSIXlt”**

later i need to find out the Year,month,dayofmonth,hors,min,sec for that i have this snippet

```
df1$Year <- df1$pTime$year-100  #Year
df1$Month <- df1$pTime$mon+1  #Month 1-12
df1$Day <-  df1$pTime$mday  #day of month
df1$Hour <- df1$pTime$hour  #0â??23: hours
df1$Min <- df1$pTime$min
df1$Sec <- df1$pTime$sec
df1$WeekOfYear <- strftime(df1$pTime, format="%W")
```

and i am executing above script using following syntax,

```
 bin/spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0  /home/script/analysis.R 

 **Error in as.POSIXlt.default(df1$timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") : 
  do not know how to convert 'df1$timestamp' to class “POSIXlt”
  Calls: as.POSIXlt -> as.POSIXlt.default
  Execution halted**
```

How can i get rid of the error, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I don't get any error with your code. I tried with a character vector of dates such as the one you cite. you should give us the `str(df1)`.

Comment: Because i am using this in sparkR script.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your timestamp by using `as.POSIXct`

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2015-12-01 00:04:39")
```

and then using `lubridate` package, you can extract all the information

```
library(lubridate)

year(x)
#[1] 2015
month(x)
#[1] 12
day(x)
#[1] 1
hour(x)
#[1] 0
minute(x)
#[1] 4
second(x)
#[1] 39
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract parts of datetime values by

```
x <- Sys.time()
format(x, format="%Y")
```

for example. See

```
?strptime
```

for all options.

I can not reconstruct the first part of your question. What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 2):

firstly, you can index your data.frame using without using the `ifelse` case

```
df1[colnames(df1) %in% "timestamp"]
```

To convert you entire column of format `2015-12-01 00:04:39`

```
as.POSIXlt(strptime(as.character(df1[colnames(df1) %in% "timestamp"]), 
                     format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
           format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had **'trans_dtime'** column type **string** in dataframe. i have converted **'trans_dtime'** column to **timestamp** type using **SparkR**

```
printSchema(df)
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- trans_dtime: string (nullable = true)
```

---

```
df$trans_dtime <- from_utc_timestamp(date_format(df$trans_dtime, "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "GMT")
```

---

```
printSchema(df)
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- trans_dtime: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Hope it will help you. :)